# Parse JSON key containing JSON string

Tags: postman

I have a response body that has a key "response".  I am trying to get the value of transactionLogId.

```
{
"response": "{\"messageHeader\":{\"transactionLogId\":\"DCBB028A_B543_4DF6_B8C0_DF1215324841\",\"action\":\"BOOK\"},\"properties\":{\"contextObjects\":[{\"recordId\":\"a0D1U000001bFMPUA2\",\"statusSummary\":{\"FaultRecInfoArray\":{\"FaultMsgRec\":{\"ErrLoc\":\"DDACCTADD\",\"ErrCat\":\"Error\",\"ErrElem\":\"AccountId.AcctId AccountId.AcctType\",\"ErrDesc\":\"Account already exists\",\"ErrElemVal\":\"209171/D\",\"ErrCode\":\"2\"}}},\"externalId\":\"209171\",\"relatedObjects\":[{\"recordId\":\"0011U0000052ESEQA2\",\"statusSummary\":\"Already existed on core.\",\"externalId\":\"JAA0100\",\"statusCode\":\"BOOKED\"}],\"statusCode\":\"NOT_PERSISTED\"}]}}"
```

}

Here is the script:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
var setId = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonData.response));
console.log("Id:"+setId.transactionLogId);
```

My console output:

```
Id:undefined
```

I've changed the console.log to just console.log("Id:"+setId);  with the console output:

```
Id:{"messageHeader":{"transactionLogId":"DCBB028A_B543_4DF6_B8C0_DF1215324841","action":"BOOK"},"properties":{"contextObjects":[{"recordId":"a0D1U000001bFMPUA2","statusSummary":{"FaultRecInfoArray":{"FaultMsgRec":{"ErrLoc":"DDACCTADD","ErrCat":"Error","ErrElem":"AccountId.AcctId AccountId.AcctType","ErrDesc":"Account already exists","ErrElemVal":"209171/D","ErrCode":"2"}}},"externalId":"209171","relatedObjects":[{"recordId":"0011U0000052ESEQA2","statusSummary":"Already existed on core.","externalId":"JAA0100","statusCode":"BOOKED"}],"statusCode":"NOT_PERSISTED"}]}}
```

I'm not sure why I can't get it to parse correctly.  Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you calling `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: Out of sheer desperation at this point.  After further testing I've realized I don't need to call it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for JSON.stringify. It is already a string.

Based on the information above, you need to do responseBody.response

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody.response);
```

I see that you are receiving a JSON object from the server that has a response attribute. And the response attribute is a raw JSON string. So you need to do the above.

**Edit:** I tried your mock API and it works as I suggested above for me. This time, I will provide the full call though:

```
$.ajax({url: "https://my.api.mockaroo.com/postman_response.json?key=5cbc25b0&__method=POST", success: function(responseBody){
console.log(JSON.parse(responseBody.response).messageHeader.transactionLogId);
}});
```

Comment: I'm still unable to out the value of the transactionLogId key.  Using this results in a an error, JSONError | Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Comment: Is the website public?

Comment: I just created a mock api.
https://my.api.mockaroo.com/postman_response.json?key=5cbc25b0&__method=POST

Comment: I tested it and added the fully-qualified reference to the transactionLogId. It works for me when I test your mock API

Answer (score 0):

I am setting my console output successfully by using the following script.

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
var output = JSON.parse(jsonData.response);
console.log(output.messageHeader.transactionLogId);
```

Thank you